# Does BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE not get changed if we are using multiple APK's

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, android-version

I am creating [multiple apk's](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split) for each `ABI`, I did this to assign separate version code to each apk.

```
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a':1, mips:2, x86:3]

import com.android.build.OutputFile
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseAbiVersionCode =
                project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `dafaultConfig`, and the following `versionCode` is for `universalApk`

```
 defaultConfig {
        versionCode 74
        versionName "1.0.2"
}
```

I append the `versionCode` with each service request, I also display the `versionCode` in one of the activity. So i need the correct `versionCode` to perform these operations, I use this code to get `versionCode`

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

Now the problem is that, it displays the `versionCode` that is stated in `defaultConfig` and not the one that actually represents the build.

I need to know that how can i get the `versionCode` that is assigned to this build, that may be some number greater than `1000`, and not the one that is assigned in `dafaultConfig`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check version code you can use PackageInfo and PackageManager

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;   //version name
    int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;      //version code
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not read build config file, build config file will display the default configuration.

You should use PackageInfo

```
  try {
            PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            String version = pInfo.versionName;
            Log.e("name","name"+version);
            Log.e("Code","code"+pInfo.versionCode);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Which will display 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for mips and 1003 for x86

Answer (score 1):

I asked something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502548/buildconfig-versioncode-is-not-reflecting-the-actual-versioncode-after-updating).

Since accessing `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` seems to be less expensive than accessing the `PackageInfo`, I thought in a workaround to keep using the BuildConfig.java to retrieve the `versionCode` in these situations, it's not as good as we had before with `mergedFlavor.versionCode` that overrides the `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` but since this change was made to improve the build time I'm more than happy to live with it.

First you should set the `versionCode` in each flavor instead of `defaultConfig`, example:

```
flavorDimensions 'default'

productFlavors {
    hellotest {
        versionCode 20
    }

    hellotest1 {
        versionCode 10
    }
}
```

Then and updating your code from above:

```
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a':1, mips:2, x86:3]

import com.android.build.OutputFile
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // Get the versionCode statically defined in each flavor.
    def versionCode = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode
    // Create a custom buildConfigField with the versionCode
    variant.buildConfigField('int', 'OVERRIDEN_VERSION_CODE', "${versionCode}")
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseAbiVersionCode =
                project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode
                    // Update the BuildConfig.OVERRIDEN_VERSION_CODE with the new versionCode.
                    // OVERRIDEN_VERSION_CODE is just an example name, you can give the name you want.
                    variant.buildConfigField('int', 'OVERRIDEN_VERSION_CODE', "${output.versionCodeOverride}") 
        }
    }
}
```

After this you will have the correct `versionCode` accessible through `BuildConfig.OVERRIDEN_VERSION_CODE` anywhere in the project.

Comment: Gradle Plugin version: `3.3.0-rc01`. ERROR: Could not find method buildConfigField() for arguments [int, VERSION_BUILD, 7] on ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=FullSplit{type=FULL_SPLIT, fullName=exampleArm64-v8aDebug, filters=[FilterData{type=ABI, value=arm64-v8a}], versionCode=7, versionName=1.2.0}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.

Comment: how are you setting the buildConfigField?
In case you want an int it should be something like this: `variant.buildConfigField 'int', 'VERSION_BUILD', '7'` 
Don't forget the '

Comment: I am trying to set an ABI `variant.buildConfigField('String', 'ABI', "\"\"")`.

Comment: The error you got is not related with `variant.buildConfigField('String', 'ABI', "\"\"")`
This `variant.buildConfigField('String', 'ABI', "\"\"")` works just fine you can try it in an empty project.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. This was my fault. Do you by chance know how can I set a different build config value to each ABI I create? For now the solution you proposed sets the build config value just to the `flavorBuildType` (not to the specific outputs). I tried iterating over each output in a variant and tried to do `output.buildConfigField()` but it errors as there is no such method. Have you had such a problem?

Comment: Not sure if I got it. Do you want to have multiple ABIs per variant in the buildConfig?

Comment: I already have them. And I am already setting different version codes to each of the ABIs I create. For instance, I use `android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> variant.outputs.each { output -> output.versionCodeOverride = 0 } } /* depends on ABI */`. But I don't know how to set a specific value to build config depending on ABI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `BuildConfig`, make sure you're importing the *correct* one for your build and not one which belongs to a different module/lib.

That said, a more conflict-proof method is certainly using the `PackageManger` as @lib4 suggested, but with a slight tweak: Using `pInfo.getLongVersionCode()` in Java or `pInfo.longVersionCode` in Kotlin instead of `pInfo.versionCode` (which was deprecated in API 28)

```
try {
    val pInfo =this.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
    val version = pInfo.versionName;   //version name
    val versionCode = pInfo?.longVersionCode   //version code
} catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```